# Visibility of inherited class methods does not make sense?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

The following code represents my effort at a Unit of work.

**Interfaces:**

```
public interface IUnitOfWork
{
    IFieldRepository FieldRepository { get; }
    void Save();
}

public interface IFieldRepository
{
    IEnumerable<Field> GetAllFields( int page, int amount, string sortByKey, SortDirection sortDirection );
}
```

**Concrete unit of work class:**

```
public class EFUnitOfWork : IDisposable, IUnitOfWork
{
    private EFDbContext context = new EFDbContext();

    private IFieldRepository fieldRepository;

    public IFieldRepository FieldRepository
    {
        get
        {

            if( this.fieldRepository == null )
            {
                this.fieldRepository = new EFFieldRepository( context );
                // At this point i can see this.fieldRepository.Insert() absolutely fine
            }
            return fieldRepository;
        }
    }

    // ...
```

**Concrete Field repository:**

```
public class EFFieldRepository : EFGenericRepository<Field>, IFieldRepository
{
    public EFFieldRepository( EFDbContext context )
        : base( context )
    {}

    // ...
```

**Concrete Generic repository:**

```
public class EFGenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    internal protected EFDbContext context;
    internal protected DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;

    public EFGenericRepository( EFDbContext context )
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public virtual void Insert( TEntity entity )
    {
        dbSet.Add( entity );
    }

    // ...
```

**Controller class:**

```
public class FieldController : Controller
{
    IUnitOfWork unitOfWork;

    public FieldController( IUnitOfWork unitOfWork )
    {
        this.unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

    // GET: Field
    public ActionResult List()
    {
        unitOfWork.FieldRepository.Insert( ... ); // This method isn't visible? But GetAllFields is visible
        return View();
    }
}
```

The problem comes when from within my controller, I cannot access the methods that should be inherited from my `EFFieldRepository`?

If you take a look at the comment inside the `EFUnitOfWork.FieldRepository`, I can see them at that point

What is preventing the inherited class displaying its methods?

Comment: How the code in a controller looks like?

Comment: I've now added controller to OP

Comment: Your `Insert` method should __not__ be visible at the point in the code you describe. Your field is of the type `IFieldRepository` .. which does not expose the `Insert` method in its contract - therefore, what you're saying is happening is incorrect. Your code is either incorrect here .. or your Intellisense is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`unitOfWork.FieldRepository` has type `IFieldRepository` so only `GetAllFields()` is visible:

```
IFieldRepository repository = unitOfWork.FieldRepository;
repository.GetAllFields();
```

You need either cast it to `EFGenericRepository<Field>, IFieldRepository` (*don't do it!*) or add this method to the interface:

```
public interface IFieldRepository
{
    void Insert(Field entity);
}
```

Being `virtual` doesn't make any difference here, you can remove it.

---

But instead I'd have a generic interface for all repositories:

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
    IEnumerable<T> GetAll(int page, int amount, string sortByKey, SortDirection sortDirection);
}
```

or its better version modified to work with EF:

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
    IEnumerable<T> GetAll();

    IEnumerable<T> GetAll(int page, int amount, Expression<Func<IQueryable<T>, Func<T, object>, IEnumerable<T>>> sort);
}
```

Usage:

```
repository.GetAll(x, y, (seq, p) => seq.OrderBy(p => p.Name));
```

Comment: Thanks man, was being dumb with my last question. Alright, will do this then... thanks so much!

Does the unit of work look about right?

Comment: Also see http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/246361/Handle-GridView-OnSorting-using-LINQ, because you use `SortDirection` for order direction, and there are much better ways to do it.

Comment: @Jimmyt1988: I'm not sure you need a Unit of Work here at all, it looks like an unnecessary layer. I'd inject just `IRepository<T>` into `TController` (i.e FieldRepository into FieldController), and inject DataContext directly into a repository.

Comment: @Jimmyt1988: You can replace `sortByKey` with `Func<T, object` so it would be a lambda like `f => f.SomePropertyOfField`.

Comment: @Jimmyt1988: And replace `SortDirection` with `Func<IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable<T>>` so it would be `seq => seq.OrderBy(prop)` or `seq => seq.OrderByDescending(prop)` where `prop` is a property selector from the previous comment.